# mysql apply only required changes

Tags: mysql, database-migration, liquibase, database-versioning, database-mirroring

I have 2 DB instances running on `dev` and `prod`.

In `dev` I have created a table `students` with the following schema

```
create table students (name varchar(20), age int, place varchar(100));
```

I created the same DB in `prod` using the above `dev` schema.

Now I have changed dev schema 3 times

```
alter table students modify name varchar(50);

alter table students modify name varchar(100);

alter table students modify name varchar(150);
```

once the `dev` DB is stable, I want to apply these changes to `prod`.
since all the changes I made in `dev` is only on one field, there is no need to apply 3 `alter` commands in `prod`. Instead, I need to apply only the 3rd `alter` command in `prod`.

Is there any tool available to apply only required changes?

Comment: Please provide more information like "Which tools you are using to apply the schema changes"?

Comment: i am not using any tools yet. i am searching for the best tool for these kind of database schema changes. @SandeshJain

Comment: You can use SQL Yog or MySql workbench to connect multiple database and transfer/migrate database. My favorite is SQLYog....supports most of DBs

Comment: actually, my requirement is to find the schema changes and apply them in another db. @MangeshSathe

Comment: Create DDL trigger to track all model changes with login names, dates, object name, modification statement and all other things you could need

Comment: If you were to use Liquibase, Liquibase would not be able to do this automatically. You would need to add more information to the changelog. In general, any tool that uses 'migrations' will be similar. Any tool that uses 'diffs' to create migrations scripts "on the fly" will be able to do this, but diff-based database migrations have their own issues. Here are some articles discussing the tradeoffs:
https://dotnetvibes.com/2018/04/16/database-delivery-state-based-vs-migration-based/
https://dev.to/pesse/one-does-not-simply-update-a-database--migration-based-database-development-527d